# how do you manage a dialogue in a car

Tags: dialogue, cars, lavalier

hi, i apologize for probably stupid question, but how do you manage a dialogue with boom or lavalier in a moving car? how do you get the best result?

Answer (score 1):

[Rigging Microphones in Cars](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/11846/rigging-microphones-in-cars)

Answer (score 1):

The old lavs in the sun visors rig works a treat. I've also gotten great results rigging them to the head rests (if characters turn to talk to people in the back seats) and around the side windows (if characters are talking to people outside the car).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a MKH 50 attached to a magic arm which is hooked onto a wooden board and placed on the floor at the passengers seat, stabilized by sandbags. The mic is then angled into the middle of the car close to the gear shift so that the polar pattern will pick up both actors. Also, use 2 omni directional lavs hidden in the visors with the transmitter as a back up. I have done this a few times and it works very well.

Good luck.